# Java For loop output

Tags: java, for-loop

```
private void printRandoms() {
    int value;
    for (int i = 2; i < 8; i = i + 2) {
        value = (int) (Math.random() * 2 + 3);
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why there are 2 possible outputs and why they are 3,3,4 and 4,3,4. And also what does this i = i + 2 mean in here?

Comment: If you have debugger please use it to stop program and explore variables value. Or you can use `System.out.println("i="+i)` and similar statements to output intermediate values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) produces a random floating point number between 0 and 1 (not including 1).  You multiply that by 2, so now the value is between 0 and 2 (not including 2).  Then you add 3, so the value is between 3 and 5 (not including 5).  The `(int)` cast loses the decimal information, so the possibilities left are 3 and 4.

The `i = i + 2` means set `i` to the expression `i + 2`, i.e. it adds 2 to `i`.

Comment: can you explain why it would give me output of 3 3 4 and 4 3 4?

Comment: like why are there 3 numbers in each possible output?

Comment: The values of `i` that are looped through are only 2, 4, and 6.  When `i` reaches 8, the `for` loop condition is `false` and the loop is terminated.

Comment: There are other possible _combinations_ of numbers to be outputted -- I just got `4 4 4`, but exactly 3 numbers are produced.

Comment: why it is only 3 numbers can be produced? doesn't it keep looping until the output reaches 8, in that case wouldn't `4 4 4` keep going until it reaches 8?

Comment: Keep track of the value of i during the loop's execution. 1) First turn of the loop, i =2 2) Second turn, i = i + 2, i.e., i = 4 3) Third turn, i = i + 2 again or i = 6. At the fourth turn of the loop, i would be equal to 8 ... but the loop only executes until i < 8, so it won't execute a fourth time. Make sense?